# Problem with composer in the mediawiki project

Tags: composer-php, mediawiki

Dears, I have a question about mediawiki 1.25 version. The composer not work. I run below command in mediawiki core:

```
$composer update --no-dev
```

bellow the error:

```
> ComposerHookHandler::onPreUpdate
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\VersionConstraint' not found in /var/www/wiki/src/mediawiki-REL1_25/includes/composer/ComposerPackageModifier.php on line 53

Fatal error: Class 'Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\VersionConstraint' not found in /var/www/wiki/src/mediawiki-REL1_25/includes/composer/ComposerPackageModifier.php on line 53
```

I read the documentation from wiki, and there recommend use composer to solve problems with dependencies.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem. If this is a bug within MediaWiki, you should report it to their bugtracker

Comment: It sounds a bit like your version of composer is incompatible with the MediaWiki version you're using, so you could try to use a different version of composer.